# RegionPlot only shows part of ImplicitRegion?

Tags: plotting, regions

In this very simple example a region consisting of two lines forming a right angle is defined as

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(1 <= r < 3 && z == 0) || (r == 3 &&0 <= z <= 2), {z, r}];
```

but

```
RegionPlot[reg ]
```

[image]

only shows vertical part of it.

I tried `PlotRange`, `PlotPoints` without success and checked

```
RegionMember[reg, {1, 3}] (* True*)
```

How to show the complete region?
Thanks!

Comment: `PlotRange->{{-1,10},{-1,10}}` ?

Comment: Thanks, no effect in Mathematica v12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in V12.2 (Mac). It does what seems obivous and is probably done in V13 (discretize each component represented by the arguments to `Or`):

```
RegionPlot[
 List @@ Thread[reg, Or] // Map@DiscretizeRegion // RegionUnion // 
  Evaluate]
```

[image]

Comment: Really clever, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version
(* 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022) *)
```

`RegionPlot` not always automatic discretize the region.

```
DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
RegionPlot[%]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In v12.2 your solution doesn't work unfortunately. What's your Mathematica version?